# Does addition imply an order?

Tags: arithmetic

Consider any integer, suppose a number 3. We can break any such integer
down into a sequence of 1's. So, we can write:
$$
3\equiv1+1+1
$$

3 represents what we get when we add 1 to 1 to another 1. Conceptually,
what I am getting confused with, is the fact that notionally, at least
according to this definition, there is one unit at the beginning,
to which we add another, and yet a third. There seems to be a sequence
here, which would imply there being an order. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What sort of "order" are you talking about?  "*But these 1's are interchangable*" Are they?  I have three pets that I could line up if I wanted to... I have a dog, a cat and a parrot.  I could just as well have said I have a parrot, a dog, and a cat.  If I were to take a picture of them lined up in the first way it would be a noticeably different picture than if they were lined up in the other way.

Comment: The end result is very likely going to be "*There is if you want there to be and there isn't if you don't.*"  Compare: [Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)), [Partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), and [Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Comment: OK- I'll try to put a finger on the confusion. If 2 is indeed 1+1, we think of 1 being added to 1 which already existed. But, it is not clear which one existed, and which one the other 1 was added to?

Comment: If you are purely interested in the definition of the number $2$ and the definition of the number $3$ and so on... this is generally done via the usage of the [Successor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function) where we have $3:= S(S(S(0)))$ or $3:=S(S(1))$ depending on if you began by defining zero or began by defining one.  Similarly, with the definition by [Von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Von_Neumann_ordinals) you have $3 := 2\cup \{2\}$, the successor function being defined here as $S(x)=x\cup \{x\}$ starting with $0=\emptyset$

Comment: In this way of thinking of it, the definition of $3$ was *not* as $1+1+1$, but rather defined as the number after *the number after one*.  The definition of $3$ came before the definition of addition.

Comment: Could you please provide some intuition as to why defining 3 as a successor function is different from adding 3 1's? How can the definition, successfor function or otherwise, preclude the notion that it combines the number 3 represents the combination of a specific number of units? (3 1's)? Please feel free to answer it instead as a comment, and I will be happy to award this bounty to you, as you already have provided much of an answer.

Comment: Is this a valid way to rephrase your question: "does 1+1+1 mean (1+1)+1 or 1+(1+1)?" ?

Comment: That would be one implication of the question. Let me be particular. Let us say we label one unit A, the other B, and the third C.  Naturally A+B+C=3, as are all the other combinations as well. The question then is: when we think of the number 3, how can we avoid thinking about a particular order embodied in the quantity itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JMoravitz pointed out in the comments, the usual way of defining arithmetic axiomatically is by use of a successor function, along with some initial number. They also pointed out that this typically ends up being a question about what your axioms are, and the answer may change with different axioms. For simplicity we'll assume the number $0$ exists, and that for each number $n$, there is another number $S(n)$, which we call the successor of $n$. We define the constant symbols $1:=S(0)$  and $2:=S(1)$ and $3:=S(2)$. Addition is then defined using the successor function.

One of the simplest possible axioms for addition is that $n+0=n$ for every $n$. The next simplest axiom would be $n+S(m)=S(n+m)$. In the standard case, these would constitute a recursive definition for addition. As some immediate consequences, for any $n$ we have:
\begin{align}
&n+1 = n+S(0) = S(n+0) = S(n) \\
&n+2 = n+S(1) = S(n+1) = S(S(n)) \\
&n+3 = n+S(2) = S(n+2) = S(S(S(n)))
\end{align}

So in particular, $1+1=S(1)=2$. Then we can use these in the case of $3$ to get:
\begin{align}
(1+1)+1 =& 2+1 = S(2) = 3 \\
1+(1+1) =& 1+2 = S(S(1)) = 3
\end{align}

So we have seen that even with these few axioms, the order of summation does not matter in this case. Whenever this happens, it's conventional to omit the parentheses and write $1+1+1$. When we (or a computer) actually performs the calculation, we do need to pick an order for what gets added first, but the order we pick doesn't matter because it's always $3$ in the end.